# Jackson infinite loops many-to-one one-to-many relation

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jackson

I have two model:

```
Parent:
id     name       childrenIds
1      parent1    1,2
2      parent2    3

Child
id     parentId
1      1
2      1
3      2
```

When I am trying to serialize this models using Jackson, stack overflow error occurred.

I am try to resolve my problem using mentioned solution in this question:
[Infinite Recursion with Jackson JSON and Hibernate JPA issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325387/infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-and-hibernate-jpa-issue)

- But when I am using `@JsonIgnore` I can't access child or parent node at all.
- When I am using `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` annotations, only one way serialization is possible. means that if `childrenIds` in parent marked as JsonManagedReference , serializing a child object does not contain parent
- With using `@JsonIdentityInfo` , every object only serialized one time. means that after serialization children[0].parent has value but children[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325387/infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-and-hibernate-jpa-issue).parent is undefined, because parnt1 is serialized one time

How can I serialize an object using jackson, with complete bidirectional access

Comment: Could you paste what you have done so far?